# Random string generator doesn't edit my string array (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, string

My string randomizing function outputs empty strings.

I've already seen that inputting it manually works perfectly, I've tried using pointers but it only gives me error outputs.

```
void random(string Arr[], int ArrSize){
    for(int i = 0; i < ArrSize; i++){
        int StrSize = rand() % 8 + 3;
        for(int j = 0; j < StrSize; j++){
           (Arr[i])[j] = rand() % 74 + 48;
        }
    }
}



int main(){
    int ArrSize;
    cout << "Input string array length: \n";
    cin >> ArrSize;
    string StringArr[ArrSize];
    random(StringArr, ArrSize);
    lexCombSort(StringArr, ArrSize);
    for(int i = 0; i < ArrSize; i++) cout << StringArr[i] << " \n";

    return 0;
}
```

I wanted the code to output an array of strings (and sort it in another function), but it doesn't output anything.

Comment: `int StrSize = rand() % 8 + 3;` you aren't resizing your string to match this.  In other words, you have Undefined Behavior because you will write into memory that is outside of the allocated bounds of your string object.

Comment: Plus we can add that `cin >> ArrSize;
    string StringArr[ArrSize];` is not legal C++ (array bounds must be constants, not variables). It you are going to use strings you might as well use vectors `cin >> ArrSize;
    vector<string> StringArr(ArrSize);`. Now it's legal.

Answer (score 2):

You should append characters to strings rather than trying to override them:

```
Arr[i].push_back (rand() % 74 + 48);
```

instead of

```
(Arr[i])[j] = rand() % 74 + 48;
```

Comment: Note that overriding will still work, but only if the string buffer is large enough to fit all of your writes.  By using `push_back` you don't need to care about the buffer size before doing the writes; it will resize itself automatically.

Comment: Overriding does not increase length, so strings remain empty, despite the fact that their buffers become dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient, especially for longer strings, might be:

```
void random(string Arr[], int ArrSize){
    for(int i = 0; i < ArrSize; i++){
        int StrSize = rand() % 8 + 3;
        Arr [i].append (StrSize, 0);
        for(int j = 0; j < StrSize; j++){
           (Arr[i])[j] = rand() % 74 + 48;
        }
    }
}
```

since it avoids potential multiple allocations in `push_back`.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IjOh9uDik0NNqoYd)